# Sort results non-lexicographically?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to display some results in a human-readable way. For the purposes of this question, some of them are numbers, some are letters, some are a combination of the two.

I'm trying to figure out how I could get them to sort like this:

```
input = ['1', '10', '2', '0', '3', 'Hello', '100', 'Allowance']
sorted_input = sorted(input)
print(sorted_input)
```

Desired Results:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '10', '100', 'Allowance', 'Hello']
```

Actual results:

```
['0', '1', '10', '100', '2', '3', 'Allowance', 'Hello']
```

I'm having trouble coming up with how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1 - Install natsort module**

```
pip install natsort
```

**2 - Import natsorted**

```
>>> input = ['1', '10', '2', '0', '3', 'Hello', '100', 'Allowance']

>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> natsorted(input)
['0', '1', '2', '3', '10', '100', 'Allowance', 'Hello']
```

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort

Comment: I'm glad to see that `natsort` is useful for people other than just me. Thanks for recommending it!

Comment: Thanks for writing the `natsort` module, @SethMMorton.  It's really handy.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the code in the following link about natural sorting order very useful in the past:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Comment: This was really useful towards understanding how it works, I was torn between marking this and Mingyu's, I ended up going with Mingyu's since it actually has a usable solution, but this was a great read.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.  For purposes of comparison, it converts strings that *can* be converted to an integer to that integer, and leaves other strings alone:

```
def key(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

sorted_input = sorted(input, key=key)
```

Comment: I think you missed this part "some are a combination of the two.". Also won't work in Python3 because "unorderable types"

Comment: Nope, I saw it but ignored it, because they didn't say a word about what they wanted in that case ;-)

Comment: "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess." I should have known better :)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case:

```
def mySort(l):
    numbers = []
    words = []
    for e in l:
        try:
            numbers.append(int(e))
        except:
            words.append(e)
    return [str(i) for i in sorted(numbers)] + sorted(words)

print mySort(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split up the list, sort, then put it back together. Try something like this:

```
numbers = sorted(int(i) for i in input_ if i.isdigit())
nonnums = sorted(i for i in input_ if not i.isdigit())
sorted_input = [str(i) for i in numbers] + nonnums
```

You'll have to do something more complicated than `isdigit` if you can have non-integers.

If this doesn't cover your "some are a combination of the two," please elaborate what that means and what output you expect from them.

(Not tested, but should convey the idea.)