# Splitting, merging, sorting CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several CSV files containing measurements from several sensors

s1.CSV :

```
date;hour;source;values
01/25/12;10:20:00;a; 88 -84 27
01/25/12;10:30:00;a; -80
01/25/12;10:50:00;b; -96 3 -88
01/25/12;09:00:00;b; -97 101
01/25/12;09:10:00;c; 28
```

s2.CSV :

```
date;hour;source;values
01/25/12;10:20:00;a; 133
01/25/12;10:25:00;a; -8 -5
```

I'd like to create one CSV by source (a/b/c) with every measure in separated column sorted by date and hour

a.CSV :

```
date;hour;source;s1;s2
01/25/12;10:20:00;a; 88 -84 27; 133
01/25/12;10:25:00;a; ; -8 -5
01/25/12;10:30:00;a; -80;
```

...

I'm stuck here :

```
import glob
import csv
import os
os.system('cls')

sources = dict()
sensor = 0

filelist = glob.glob("*.csv")

for f in filelist:
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(f),delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
#       date = row['date'] # date later
        hour = row['hour']
        val = row['values']
        source = row['source']

        if not sources.has_key(source): # new source
            sources[source] = list()
#       
        sources[source].append({'hour':hour, 'sensor'+`sensor`:val})

    sensor+=1
```

I'm not sure the data structure is good to sort. I also fell like repeating column name.

Comment: Don't spare us your first attempts! You want to _learn_, right? Let us help you improve your own efforts.

Comment: More importantly, if you don't show us your attempts, this question will have to be closed for not "demonstrat[ing] a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Comment: Yes, please post what you have as it is more of a motivation to edit than create from scratch. Unless you just want pseudocode ("create a dictionary with time as the key...")

Comment: I would suggest using the Pandas package. I am writing up an example solution that might help you with further similar cases. 10 min!

Comment: Sorry for first post without code, I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple files, each corresponding to a given "sensor", with the identity of the sensor in the filename. You want to read the files, then write them out in to separate files again, this time divided by "source", with the data from the different sensors combined into several final rows.

Here's what I think you want to do:

1. Read the data in, and build a nested dictionary data structure, as follows:
2. The top level key would be the source (e.g. `'a'`).
3. The second level will be keyed by a `(date, time)` tuple.
4. The inner most level will be keyed by sensor, taken from the filename, and have the actual sensor readings as values.
5. You'd also want to keep track of all the sensors that have been seen.
6. To write the data out, you'd loop over the items of the outermost dictionary, creating a new output file for each one.
7. The rows of each file would be determined by sorting the keys of the next dictionary.
8. The last value of each row would be formed by concatenating the values of the innermost dict, filling in an empty string for any missing values.

Here's some code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import glob
import os

# data structure is data[source][date, time][sensor] = value, with "" as default value
data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str)))
sensors = []

filelist = glob.glob("*.csv")

# read old files
for fn in filelist:
    sensor = os.path.splitext(fn)[0]
    sensors.append(sensor)
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            date = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%m/%d/%y')
            data[row['source']][date, row['hour']][sensor] = row['values']

sensors.sort() # note, this may not give the best sort order
header = ['date', 'hour', 'source'] + sensors

for source, source_data in data.iteritems():
    fn = "{}.csv".format(source)
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow(header)
        for (date, time), hour_data in sorted(source_data.items()):
            values = [hour_data[sensor] for sensor in sensors]
            writer.writerow([date.strftime('%m/%d/%y'), time, source] + values)
```

I only convert the date field to an internal type because otherwise sorting based on dates won't work correctly (dates in January 2013 would appear before those in February 2012). In the future, consider using ISO 8601 style date formating, `YYYY-MM-DD`, which can be safely sorted as a string. The rest of the values are handled only as strings with no interpretation.

The code assumes that the `sensor` values can be ordered lexicographically. This is likely if you only have a few of them, e.g. `s1` and `s2`. However, if you have a `s10`, it will be sorted ahead of `s2`. To solve this you'll need a "natural" sort, which is more complicated than I can solve here (but see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624844/sort-results-non-lexicographically) for more info).

One final warning: This solution may do bad things if you run it mutliple times in the same folder. That's because the output files, e.g. `a.csv` will be seen by `glob.glob('*.csv')` as input files when you run again.

Comment: Very clear, thanks for the data collection, that's what I needed. You opened your files twice : csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";")

Comment: Whoops, that extra `open` was a copy/paste error. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Using your data provided, I cooked up something using Pandas. Please see code below.

The output, granted, is non-ideal, as the `hour` and `source` get repeated within a column. As I am learning too, I'd also welcome any expert input on whether Pandas can do what the OP is asking for!

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s1 = pd.read_csv('s1.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=True)

In [3]: s1
Out[3]: 
       date      hour source      values
0  01/25/12  10:20:00      a   88 -84 27
1  01/25/12  10:30:00      a         -80
2  01/25/12  10:50:00      b   -96 3 -88
3  01/25/12  09:00:00      b     -97 101
4  01/25/12  09:10:00      c          28

In [4]: s2 = pd.read_csv('s2.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=True)

In [5]: s2
Out[5]: 
       date      hour source  values
0  01/25/12  10:20:00      a     133
1  01/25/12  10:25:00      a   -8 -5

In [6]: joined = s1.append(s2)

In [7]: joined
Out[7]: 
       date      hour source      values
0  01/25/12  10:20:00      a   88 -84 27
1  01/25/12  10:30:00      a         -80
2  01/25/12  10:50:00      b   -96 3 -88
3  01/25/12  09:00:00      b     -97 101
4  01/25/12  09:10:00      c          28
0  01/25/12  10:20:00      a         133
1  01/25/12  10:25:00      a       -8 -5

In [8]: grouped = joined.groupby('hour').sum() 

In [9]: grouped.to_csv('a.csv')

In [10]: grouped
Out[10]: 
                      date source          values
hour                                             
09:00:00          01/25/12      b         -97 101
09:10:00          01/25/12      c              28
10:20:00  01/25/1201/25/12     aa   88 -84 27 133
10:25:00          01/25/12      a           -8 -5
10:30:00          01/25/12      a             -80
10:50:00          01/25/12      b       -96 3 -88
```

Comment: Sweet, I guess one can rename "values" field to "sensorX" and group with s1+s2